# Cannot give dynamic value in labelText

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I tried to use

```
lblSchool.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME];
```

This give blank value. But the following codes displays value in result page.

```
lblSchool.text = @"Test Name";
```

And

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"INTL" message:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

**UPDATE**

When I removed the newlines from the text (trimmed new lines), The issue was solved.

I used the following lines of code.

```
 NSString *greeting = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    lblSchool.text = greeting;
```

Comment: then maybe your userDefaults does not have the value for your key school_name. debug it by logging

Comment: @Joshua: Actually I am new in iOS development. Can you please say how I can debug by logging!

Comment: @Joshua: And how the value is shown in UI alert but not in label which are line next to it in same function.

Comment: you can use NSLog. i.e. NSLog(@"value of userdefault is: %@",[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME]);

Comment: please, don't use `UIAlertView` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set value in `NSUserDefaults` as follows:

synchronize `NSUserDefaults` after storing values:

`synchronize` method of `NSUserDefaults` is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization, if you want use values in `NSUserDefaults` frequently or in short time then use `synchronize`(as **Russell** pointed out).

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"SchoolName" forKey:SCHOOL_NAME];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Log values and check if value actually there or not as follows:

```
NSLog(@"SchoolName is: %@",[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME]);
```

If value is actually there, then your below code should work fine:

```
lblSchool.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"INTL" message:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SCHOOL_NAME] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Comment: NSLog shows there is value in NSUserDefaults. But still lblSchool.text is not showing value

Comment: You don't need to synchronize NSUserDefaults any more  `developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize`   Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.